# snowflake: How to mention date formats when loading data from stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a csv file in s3 bucket with `Date` type columns in different formats and i need to insert them into snowflake table (eg: "DB_NAME-XX"."SCHEMA_NAME-XX"."TABLE_NAME-XX") where all columns are `Date` type

```
example (sample data) (its a stage data formatted for understanding purpose)
col_1      | col_2 | col_3    
2017/12/01 | 1996  | 20101201

after inserting into snowflake ("DB_NAME-XX"."SCHEMA_NAME-XX"."TABLE_NAME-XX") it should look like below
COL_1      | COL_2      | COL_3      
2017-12-01 | 1996-01-01 | 2010-12-01
```

I am using the following command

```
    copy into "DB_NAME-XX"."SCHEMA_NAME-XX"."TABLE_NAME-XX"
      from s3://bucket_name_xx/folder_name_xx/ credentials=(aws_key_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' aws_secret_key='yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy')
      file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|'skip_header = 1)
      validation_mode = 'RETURN_1000000_ROWS';
```

I am not sure how to mention the date format in the above command.

How to achieve my goal of inserted the data with different date formats to snowflake

Comment: I guess you'd have to do a column by column logic split when transforming during the load to the stage.

Comment: why not 2 step process? load all as string and then insert from there using a SQL - where you can convert from any format to date. In fact if tomorrow they changes date format, you can check that as well

Comment: @Santhosh is the date format is the same for one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you create a [named external stage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html) first, e.g.:

```sql
CREATE STAGE my_ext_stage
URL='s3://bucket_name_xx/folder_name_xx/' 
credentials=(aws_key_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' aws_secret_key='yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy');
```

Then assuming that your columns have the same date format for all of the values throughout the file, you can apply `to_date()` [method](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html) with the desired time format for each of the column.

```sql
copy into "DB_NAME-XX"."SCHEMA_NAME-XX"."TABLE_NAME-XX"
from (select to_date($1, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), to_date($2, 'YYYY'), to_date($3, 'YYYYMMDD') FROM @my_ext_stage)
 file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|'skip_header = 1)
 validation_mode = 'RETURN_1000000_ROWS';
```

Expected result:
[image]